# CAGR line in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I have a requirement wherein i need to draw CAGR line on column chart as shown in the image below. [image: CAGR line on Column Chart]

Can someone please help me on how to get this done.

Comment: You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Renderer.path) or [annotation plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations)

Comment: Primarily, it's just a line - so you can add a line series.  In order to get the arrow, you will need to custom create a marker with the renderer, or by extending the marker property, or by using an image as a marker.